# joining multiple tables using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Hi I am trying to do the following query using join in laravel.

```
select  advertisers.advertiserName,brands.brandName  
        ,campaigns.campaignName,banner_creatives.bannerName         
from vicinity_adman_dev.advertisers
     join vicinity_adman_dev.brands 
     join vicinity_adman_dev.campaigns
     join vicinity_adman_dev.banner_creatives

     on advertisers. advertiserId = brands.advertiserId
     where 
     banner_creatives.campaignId = campaigns.campaignId
```

What i DID so far:

```
  $campaigns =DB::table('brands')

 ->join('advertisers','brands.advertiserId' , '=','advertisers.advertiserId'               
                ->join('campaigns','banner_creatives.campaignId',
                        '=','campaigns.campaignId')  

  select('advertisers.advertiserName','brands.brandName','campaigns.campaignName','banner_creatives.bannerName')   
->get();
```

getting error on second join "**banner_creatives.campaignId**"
thanks in advance

Comment: What error do you get? Also there are several syntax errors in your code (Is that from copying or in your actual code as well?)

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'banner_creatives.bannerName' inconnu dans field list (SQL: select `advertisers`.`advertiserName`, `brands`.`brandName`, `campaigns`.`campaignName`, `banner_creatives`.`bannerName` from `brands` inner join `advertisers` on `brands`.`advertiserId` = `advertisers`.`advertiserId` inner join `campaigns` on `banner_creatives`.`campaignId` = `campaigns`.`campaignId`)

Comment: THE FIRST CODE WORKS but the laravel code give the above error

Comment: Looks to me like you forgot to join `banner_creatives`

Comment: the thing is I don't know where to put it .

Comment: Well me neither. Also Laravel doesn't support cross joins like you have them (no `on` clause)

Comment: You can add a closure to the `join()` to specify the on, ie: `->join('banner_creatives', function($join) { $join->on('banner_creatives.id', '=', 'whatevertable.id'); })`

Comment: @benJ ya it is working after adding the closure thanks

Comment: This closure is doing the same as just `join('banner_creatives', 'banner_creatives.id', '=', 'whatevertable.id')`. So no need for a closure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed one of your joins. Just add it to the others

```
$campaigns = DB::table('brands')
               ->join('advertisers', 'brands.advertiserId', '=', 'advertisers.advertiserId')
               ->join('campaigns', 'banner_creatives.campaignId', '=', 'campaigns.campaignId')
               ->join('banner_creatives', 'banner_creatives.bannerCreativeId', '=', 'other_table.bannerCreativeId')
               ->select(
                   'advertisers.advertiserName',
                   'brands.brandName',
                   'campaigns.campaignName',
                   'banner_creatives.bannerName'
               )
               ->get();
```